# Replace one column's values with NaN based on date conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to replace/update `price` column's values based on condition of: if `date` is equal to `2019-09-01`, then replace or update them with with `np.nan`, I use two methods but not worked out so far:

```
         price     pct      date
0  10379.00000  0.0242  2019/6/1
1  10608.25214     NaN  2019/9/1
2  10400.00000  0.0658  2019/6/1
3  10258.48471     NaN  2019/9/1
4  12294.00000  0.1633  2019/6/1
5  11635.07402     NaN  2019/9/1
6  12564.00000 -0.0066  2019/6/1
7  13615.10992     NaN  2019/9/1
```

Solution 1: `df.price.where(df.date == '2019-09-01', np.nan, inplace=True)`, but it replaced all `price` values with `NaN`

```
   price     pct        date
0    NaN  0.0242  2019-06-01
1    NaN     NaN  2019-09-01
2    NaN  0.0658  2019-06-01
3    NaN     NaN  2019-09-01
4    NaN  0.1633  2019-06-01
5    NaN     NaN  2019-09-01
6    NaN -0.0066  2019-06-01
7    NaN     NaN  2019-09-01
```

Solution 2: `df.loc[df.date == '2019-09-01', 'price'] = np.nan`, this didn't replace values.

```
         price     pct        date
0  10379.00000  0.0242  2019-06-01
1  10608.25214     NaN  2019-09-01
2  10400.00000  0.0658  2019-06-01
3  10258.48471     NaN  2019-09-01
4  12294.00000  0.1633  2019-06-01
5  11635.07402     NaN  2019-09-01
6  12564.00000 -0.0066  2019-06-01
7  13615.10992     NaN  2019-09-01
```

Please note `date` in excel file before `read_excel` is `2019/9/1` format, I have converted it with `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date`.

Someone why this doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: Is `date` column string or datetime?

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish object I think

Comment: Why can't you use `fillna()`?

Comment: I don’t know how to use it, because in price there are no NaNs, I need to replace values based on date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'2019-06-01'` is a string, `df.date` is a `datetime`

you should convert `df.date` to `str` to match

```
df.loc[df.date.astype(str) == '2019-06-01', 'price'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first solution works (kind of) for me, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7]]), 
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c']
)
```

The `df` should be:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
3  3  2  1
4  5  6  7
```

Then using the similiar code:

```
df.a.where(df.c != 7, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

I got the `df` as:

```
     a  b  c
0  1.0  2  3
1  4.0  5  6
2  7.0  8  9
3  3.0  2  1
4  NaN  6  7
```

Comment: Could you try with my data? Thanks.

Comment: hi @ahbon, how do you generate the data, is the "date" is a type or just string?